# how to send POST HTTP request from Google Chrome without any extensions?

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, post, webmethods

Can we send POST HTTP requests in Google Chrome when using Rest Services?
I have tried few extensions but I need directly from Chrome browser

Answer (score 2):

I think, using the URL bar will always result in a GET.

To send POST requests from a browser, set up an HTML `<form>` with `method="POST"`, use the `action` attribute for the REST-URL and input tags for other parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the post and get in the same way as the browser does.
You can use the header to put in information in key, value pair.
Here is a tutorial on how you can do it - [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-using-an-xmlhttprequest/38643171#38643171)

But it would be better if you use chrome extension POSTMAN which is very extensive and clean for testing REST services.